# Sentinel C-Plus B emulator help

Tags: emulation, dongle

I find your post.
I need an emulator for the Sentinel C-Plus B dongle.
I was able to find the dumper.
In this post I found the SC_Emulator.zip which seems to work:
http://www.reteam.org/board/attachment.php?attachmentid=6&d=1184248542
Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: If you found it, what else are you looking for?